# Netlogo: same patch cluster, same command, but different results

Tags: netlogo

I'm doing an urban simulation in which a patch color represents a land use. I start from the state showed in this picture:

[image]

then I run the following command:

```
to eliminate-isolated-patches
ask patches with [pcolor = 74] [if (count neighbors with [pcolor = 74] <= 2)
[set pcolor black
 ask neighbors with [pcolor = 74] [set pcolor black]]]
end
```

Although the model starts with the same distribution of patches and the same command is applied, it outputs different results. Sometimes this is the  result:
[image]

and other times this is the result:
[image]

As can be seen, there are variations. So I have two questions:

1) Why does this happen if the initial state and command are the same?

2) What can be done to always have the same result?

(NOTE: the blue and pink lines are GIS layers)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initial state of the world is the same, but as soon as one patch turns black inside your `ask` block, that state changes. And since `ask` runs in random order, that first patch to turn black is not always the same.

Your problem is that you check for the number of neighbors with the same color *inside* your `ask` block, where that state is unstable. The solution is probably to make that check before you start messing with patch state. You can do this by moving the check inside the `with` block:

```
to eliminate-isolated-patches
  ask patches with [ pcolor = 74 and (count neighbors with [ pcolor = 74 ] <= 2) ] [
    set pcolor black
    ask neighbors with [ pcolor = 74 ] [ set pcolor black ]
  ]
end
```

Note that this version (just like your previous version) might still leave some "isolated" patches, because they only become isolated after their neighbors turn black. If that is a problem, you might want to put the whole thing inside a `while` loop that runs until the `count patches with [ pcolor = 74 ]` is stable. If you want to do this and run into trouble, I would suggest asking a separate question.

Comment: Instead of asking a separate question, I did some coding and got the desired result using your suggestion of a `while` loop. This is the code, but have the idea that it can be improved, any suggestion?:  
    `to eliminate-isolated-patches
    while [any? patches with [pcolor = 74 and (count neighbors with [pcolor = 74] < 3)]]
    [ask patches with [pcolor = 74 and (count neighbors with [pcolor = 74] < 3)] 
    [set pcolor black]]
    end`